# Using documents obtained from a previous job

Tags: ethics, legal

What are the implications for a business that has an executive that regularly shares documents he retained after he left his previous job?

Additionally, what should an employee who's been asked to use these documents do to protect themselves?

Comment: I'm not sure what situation you're describe and even less sure about what your question is. Could you expand your question?

Comment: As the question stands we can't help you because A) you're being very vague, and B) we're not lawyers. Generally speaking, if you're uncomfortable with you company's policies you should find a new job - fast

Comment: Your first question sounds like you are from the company and one of the employees who left is sharing what, you think, might be confidential. The second suggests that you have left and want to know how to approach presenting proof of your skills via documents. Those are the conflicts I an ascertain from your questions. Please correct us :)

Answer (score 3):

If the documents are not available to the general public (eg are considered company confidential), you should not continue to use them after leaving the company unless you have explicit permission to do so.

Comment: However it's completely unclear whether this person providing them has permission for use.

Comment: Exactly. If using the documents violates the trust their owner placed in you, it's unethical.

Answer (score 2):

Not a lawyer.  NOT A LAWYER!

If you are in a situation where it feels like your morals are being compromised leave and get another job.

That being said, there is no way to offer a opinion without more information.  Has the executive said that he was not supposed to still have that documentation?  It could have been something that he was entitled to from his previous position that he is using with the knowledge and blessing of his old company. Have you asked the executive about the situation?

Unless you have been made aware with 100% certainty that the documents are stolen I dont see how you would be held responsible for using them.  But if you feel uncomfortable get out.